# Resubmitting a form via ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that i am sending data from via ajax and this gets processed by a php and and I am then displaying the processed data after getting it from this php.

I want to have a bootstrap pagination bar that after being clicked, updates a hidden value in the form(page number based on the number that was clicked) and resubmits the form and again displays the results.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax call trigger with JQuery after clicking the button. Then, you can append the result returned by you PHP API via ajax to your page.

Example:

HTML:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <button id="button">Send</button>
</form>
<div class="appendText"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
 var myData = $this.text();
 $.ajax({
            url: "process.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                data: myData

            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                $(".appendText").append(data); 
            }
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit in detail? I have this for submitting the data:
 submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    type:"GET",
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
            url:"process.php",
                    success: function(data) {